# Forbid GridView to load all views at once

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have about 700 items to display in the grid view.

On a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 this is not a problem: it has enough memory.
On a HTC Explorer the heap is overflown.

So I want to load data dynamically regarding current scroll position (N rows for screen + 5 rows as a tail). And I want to show a scrollbar which represents the position in total rows. But I don't want to draw items that I don't see.

In other words, I want to create something similar to `UITableView` in iOS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android `Adapter` works in a similar way to iOS `UITableViewDataSource`. You need to call

```
public void setAdapter (ListAdapter adapter)
```

on your `GridView` and then that Adapter will get call backs like:

```
public int getCount ()
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

It's important that you reuse `convertView` the same way you dequeue a `UITableViewCell` in

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If you do all that correctly, it will never try to load all the views at once, but only the ones currently displayed and you shouldn't have memory problems any more.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that `GridView` reuses views as good as `ListView` (I logged `getView` calls). But how you explain this fact. I load images from remote server and when the screen appears pictures SLOWLY appear one after the other, but when I scroll down other pictures are ALREADY loaded. There are 1000 items to display and 63 on one screen.

Comment: When do you trigger the download of the images? I normally trigger an `AsyncTask` from within `getView` if the image is not already downloaded. When the `AsyncTask` finishes I cache the image and refresh the view that triggered it only if it is visible.

Comment: Oh, I have a bug in my logic: there are repetitive blocks of same pics.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you found the problem. Please mark my answer as valid if you think it answers your original question.

Comment: No, this is not a _my_ bug. `GridView` receives non-null views after first screen! And those views are repetitive (I printed pointers)! ArrayList whence data is fetched is 100% correct.

Comment: That's correct, those non-null views are the ones you need to reuse. They are repeated because they are the ones that are scrolling off.

Comment: I have 1000 elements to display but only 69 views is created. So you say I need just to replace data in those views, not to re-create them?

Comment: Exactly, that is the idea. Creating views is expensive but changing their content is not so the adapter creates a pool of views that it constantly reuses for faster scrolling and better performance.

Comment: Finally I understood this mechanism of reusing (after a half year of developing). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ListView that is able to reuse View objects so that you don't have to instantiate so many objects.

Comment: `GridView` uses a `ListAdapter` and reuses views exactly the same way as `ListView`.